# Constructor for multiple objects in a class

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor

So the program I am writing requires me to input the initial values of the objects(rover) using a constructor and I am unable to figure out the proper syntax in order for it to ask me to input each step of entering coordinates and direction. If anyone is able to tell me how to make it would it would be appreciated.

```
class Rover{

private:

    string name;
    int xpos;
    int ypos;
    string direction; //Use Cardinal Directions (N,S,E,W)
    int speed; //(0-5 m/sec)

public:
    //Constructors
    Rover(int,int,string,int);
};
 Rover::Rover(int one, int two, string three, int four)
    {
        cout<<"Please enter the starting X-position: ";
        cin>>one;
        cout<<"Please enter the starting Y-position: ";
        cin>>two;
        cout<<"Please enter the starting direction (N,S,E,W): ";
        cin>>three;
        cout<<"Please enter the starting speed (0-5): ";
        cin>>four;

        xpos=one;
        ypos=two;
        direction=three;
        speed=four;

        cout<<endl; 
    }

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int spd;
    string direct;
    string nme;
    int x;
    int y;


    Rover r1(int x,int y, string direct, int spd);
    Rover r2(int x,int y, string direct, int spd);
    Rover r3(int x,int y, string direct, int spd);
    Rover r4(int x,int y, string direct, int spd);
    Rover r5(int x,int y, string direct, int spd);






    return 0;
}
```

Comment: re "requires me to input the initial values of the objects(rover) using a constructor", are  you *sure* that's a correct interpretation of the requirements? doing i/o in a constructor is generally bad practice. for one, it means the code cannot be reused without extensive modification.

Comment: This is not the proper constructor. To achive your goals, you need to first get those values (x, y, direction and speed), and than call a constructor, providing those arguments.

Comment: Cuz what the sheet says is that I need to write a constructor that accpets all 5 parameters(name,x,y,direction,speed) and initializes them

Comment: @John What is the point of making them parameters (instead of normal local variables) if you're going to not use the parameters?

Comment: Idk its just for an assignment, would you all suggest that I just call my setter functions for all the 5 variables for each rover and then use a display all data function to print out the 5 variables for the 5 rovers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of the constructors should be much simpler than that. Just initialize the member variables using the input arguments.

```
Rover::Rover(int xp, int yp, string dir, int sp) :
   xpos(xp), ypos(yp), direction(dir), speed(sp) {}
```

The code to read input and then to use the input to construct an object can be moved to a different function, preferably a non-member function.

```
Rover readRover()
{
   int xp;
   int yp;
   string dir;
   int sp;

   cout << "Please enter the starting X-position: ";
   cin >> xp;

   cout << "Please enter the starting Y-position: ";
   cin >> xp;

   cout << "Please enter the starting direction (N,S,E,W): ";
   cin >> dir;

   cout << "Please enter the starting speed (0-5): ";
   cin >> sp;

   // Construct an object with the user input data and return it.
   return Rover(xy, yp, dir, sp);  
}
```

and then, from `main` use `readRover` as many times as you wish.

```
Rover r1 = readRover();
Rover r2 = readRover();
Rover r3 = readRover();
Rover r4 = readRover();
Rover r5 = readRover();
```

The function `readRover` assumes that the user provides the correct input. If the user does not provide correct input, your program will stuck and the only way out will be to abort the program using <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> or something equivalent.

To deal with user error, you'll need to add code to detect the error first and then decide what to do with the error.

```
if ( !(cin >> xp) )
{
   // Error in reading the input.
   // Decide what you want to do.
   // Exiting prematurely is an option.
   std::cerr << "Unable to read x position." << std::endl;
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: Now that I have all the read rovers how would I go about printing them out in an array in main. I cant figure out how to move from rover 1 to rover 2 and so on